# Username Subdomain Forwarding on Multiple Pages

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking to have my website react the following way:

- www.mydomain.com - Heads to regular web pages
- username.mydomain.com - Heads to www.mydomain.com/profile.php?u=username
- username.mydomain.com/gallery - Heads to www.mydomain.com/gallery.php?u=username
- username.mydomain.com/blog - Heads to www.mydomain.com/blog.php?u=username

May have other pages do the same forwarding, but no matter how I look into it, I can't seem to find how to handle more than one page.

Comment: Clarification: The reference may not be the same for all pages (one is u=username, one is user=username) or the identifier is not the same as the page (faves redirects to favourites.php)

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1.php?u=%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Interesting, but what if the reference is not the same for all pages (one is u=username, one is user=username) or the identifier is not the same as the page (faves redirects to favourites.php?)  It's as much for curiosity as it is for helping others.

Comment: there is no easy way to do it, just specify your conditions and write your rules for them, maybe you can group them